# Django form template customization

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

New to django (and in general python). I'm trying to customize one of my forms a bit and would like to know the best way to do this.

Take for example the following, a form with 3 fields, two fields for weight entry and one for a target date.

```
class BasicFitnessGoalForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BasicFitnessGoal
        fields = ('currentWeightKg','targetWeightKg','targetDate')
        widgets = {
            'targetDate': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'formdatepicker'}),
        }
        labels = {
            'currentWeightKg' : "Current Weight",
            'targetWeightKg' : "Goal Weight",
            'targetDate' : 'Goal Date'
        }
```

I want to be able to display this form in my templates using something like goalForm.as_p() which generates html like the following:

```
<p>
 <label></label><input><input>...
```

What I am looking to do is on the weight fields insert an extra element after the input tags and customize the text and css classes. So I end up with something like this:

```
<p>
<label>Current Weight</label><input type=Number...><span class="customCss">Kg (or text I enter</span>
</p>
```

So is there anyway to accomplish this inside the model class? I know I could do this with javascript or by looping through the fields in the template instead of using the form.as_p tag. But I want to reuse this so it's cleanest if I can create a method to output the desired html wherever I want to use it.

I've seen some examples where you can set a method on the form like as_foobar where the self.html_output is returned. But I see that that only allows to specify values like "normal_row", "error_row" etc. I want to code a custom template for this form and return the html from a method on the model that I can then access from a template. (or override the as_p method for this model to return custom html depending on field).

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: You can create a custom [widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/) and use like you're using on `targetDate`.

Comment: I think a custom widget is what I want. I checked out that link and believe that if I override the render method I can produce the desired HTML and then the form will render as desired everywhere I use it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom widget as suggested in the comment is one option, another is to loop through the fields manually.

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {% for field in form %}

        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
                  <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
            {% endif %}

            {% if field.id_label = id_currentWeightKg" %}
                <span class="customCss">Kg (or text I enter</span>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

For additional information refer to the [Looping over form fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields) section in the manual.

before you do this, view the HTML source and confirm that `id_currentWeightKg` is the correct id for the field in question. If not use replace with the correct one.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to avoid looping over the fields manually as I would have to copy and paste this code in all the django templates I want to use it in. It sounds like the widget option is what I'm after. I believe by overriding the render() method on a custom widget I can output the HTML I desire. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. No disrespect intended but I didn't accept this answer since I specifically mentioned in my question I did not want to solve it this way and didn't want other viewers to think this is the only method (which is what all the other SO questions I found said). You did point me in the right direction so I've upvoted it. If you (or anyone) would like to post an answer showing an example of a custom widget and overridden "render" method. I would be happy to accept.